# PHP link changing Question mark to dot

Tags: php, email, character-encoding, type-conversion, debug-symbols

I'm sending a link inside a HTML email using PHP that should be this:

```
$link = "...mydomain.net/see_data.php?cod_ped=$cod_ped";
                                     ^
```

But I'm receiving the following link:

```
...mydomain.net/see_data.php.cod_ped=1231231";
                            ^
```

Change code to check in browser and same case... My ? changes to a simple dot.

I've tried url_encode($link), htmlentities($link), changes ? to %3F, but nothing works.

When clicking shows in browser address with a DOT and, because this, 404 error page, of course.

I seek a lot of questions here, but with the opposite case...changing a dot to question mark...

I'm using UTF8 charset.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This `$link = "...mydomain.net/see_data.php?cod_ped=$cod_ped";` should work fine, you need to add your codes and functions if you use.

Comment: Thanks and forget it. 

I´ve found an accent conversion function and that was changing all ? to a dot... It was somewhere in the middle of the long string.